# Saving data to a new row

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have an application with CakePHP and I need to insert some row of data to a table. I have followed the tutorial in the CakePHP book but it doesn't work.

```
$this->Temporary->create();
$this->Temporary->set(
    array(
        'Temporary.position_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['EmployeeAttribute']['position_id'],
        'Temporary.person_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['StatusEmployee']['person_id'],
        'Temporary.job_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Job']['id'],
        'Temporary.unit_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Unit']['id'],
        'Temporary.person_code'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['StatusEmployee']['code'],
        'Temporary.name'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['first_name'].' '.$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['middle_name'].' '.$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['last_name'],
        'Temporary.job'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Job']['short_desc']
    )
);
$this->Temporary->save();
```

I have used `create()` method, set the variable and called the save method but this code doesn't save the data to my table. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->Temporary->invalidFields());` after the save.

Comment: the result still same, it doesn't save the data to the table..but thanks for answer.

Comment: That's just supposed to help you *debug*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->Temporary->create();
$data = 
    array(
        'Temporary' => array(
            'position_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['EmployeeAttribute']['position_id'],
            'person_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['StatusEmployee']['person_id'],
            'job_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Job']['id'],
            'unit_id'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Unit']['id'],
            'person_code'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['StatusEmployee']['code'],
            'name'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['first_name'].' '.$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['middle_name'].' '.$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Person']['last_name'],
            'job'=>$employeesAttribute[$arrCount][0]['Job']['short_desc']
        )
    )
);
$this->Temporary->save($data);
```